# Tag search with newest isn't showing latest

Tags: bug, search, tag-search

There's a problem with the newest tab with a tag. I see [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47137956/great-difference-in-time-execution-groovy-vs-beanshell/47138714#47138714) asked less than an hour ago, but with [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) and [newest](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjava%5d%20is%3aquestion) or with [my tags](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=intags%3amine%20is%3aquestion) I can't see the question, only questions before 3 hours (when adding to search `is:question`),

Did something happen with tag search with newest?

**EDIT**
Now it's showing the same results from 4 hours ago.

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: also happens in incognito window without caching

Comment: No, I didn't mean browser-side caching. This is server-side caching.

Comment: it happens only when adding `is:question` to search

Comment: I am seeing this as well

Comment: Do you have one of its tags in your ignored list?

Comment: I don't have any ignored tag

Comment: For me searches on `is:question intags:mine`, `is:question score:..-1`, and `is:answer score:..-1` are all stuck at about 4 hours ago. These are searches I use every,day

Comment: I noticed it too, but it's solved now.